# How does Unit Testing in functional languages work?

Tags: unit-testing, functional-programming

I am wondering how to write good unit tests in a functional language. Testing very basic functions is not that hard but I do not understand how I should test function that use other functions.

For example:
In an object oriented world I test the very basic functionality on its own and just mock it when I test the more complex function

```
class Example {
    internal var adder: Adder = AdderImpl()
    internal var multiplier: Multiplier = MultiplierImpl()

    fun execute(n: Int, m: Int): Int =
        if (n < m) adder.add(n, m)
        else multiplier.multiply(n, m) 
}
```

if `Adder.add` and `Multiplier.multiply` are tested, I can test `Example.execute` by just mocking these and expect `adder` to be called for `n<m` and `multiplier` to be called otherwise.

But how would I do this in a functional language? I could have easy to test `add` and `multiply` functions and compose my `execute` from them

```
execute : Int -> Int -> Int
execute = 
    if n < m then add n m
    else multiply n m
```

Now to test `execute` I cannot simply expect `add` or `multiply` to be called since I cannot mock them. I would actually have to do all tests I have written for `add` already and execute them if `n<m` and do all tests for `multiply` otherwise. This means I tested these two functions two times.

So what is the correct functional way of testing the smaller functions and for the bigger function assume they work and just check if they were called if the correct conditions are met?

Comment: Why would a unit test ever need to count how often a function was called? Just test for the expected result.

Comment: Because then i'd need to test `add` and `multiply` in their own tests and copy this complete test set to the `execute` tests.
I have some already tested functionality and assume it works correctly. So all I want to test in my `execute` tests is, that I use this already tested functions in a correct way. I do not want to test their results again.

Comment: @danielspaniol that’s a strange thing to assert though - why should unit tests care about implementation details? why are you concerned *how* work gets done? what does “unit” mean to you in this context?

Comment: Maybe it gets more clear when you think about different layers in a porgram. I only want to test one layer at a time and have a reasonable amount of test cases and don't want to test through all layers at once

Comment: @Bergi `Why would a unit test ever need to count how often a function was called?` For units that changes application state instead of returning a result.

Comment: @fabpico Even if it has side effects, you can still just check whether the application state has been changed to what is expected. But notice that the question assumes functional programming.

Comment: @Bergi In a unit test, you only test the unit, not the application state. And a functional function may also change application state.

Answer (score 4):

Your `execute` function have input values and expected output - you shouldn't care about how it is implemented.
You will write tests which cover all cases of `execute` function.
If for implementation you decide to re-use `add` and `multiply` methods and all tests for `execute` function pass - good job - you have created reusable functions.

Imagine later you will decide to change behaviour of `add` method - you will change tests for `add` function to satisfy new requirements  - when you run all tests after changes - all tests pass, tests for `execute` function will pass too, because you mock it, but actually now `execute` function is broken...

Consider "unit" as unit of behaviour. Abstract only components which makes tests slow or components which uses global state of application.

Functions such `add` of `multiply` are implementation details which will be tested through "higher order" functions.

Comment: Does this mean if I have different layers (rest->logic->dataacess) that I need to test the lower layers again in all the higher layers? My rest layer should only unwrap the arguments and pass them to the logic and assume that the logic works (at least that is what I do in OOP)

Comment: It is ok to not have tests for lower layers functions. You will test them through tests of higher layers.

Comment: @danielspaniol to put it slightly differently, your lower level functions should be *obviously* correct. You don't need a test to tell you that `x -> y -> x + y` works. You probably do need a test to tell you that `f ∘ g ∘ h` works even if f, g, and h are individually simple.

Comment: I don't think this answer is answering the question. The question is how to mock `add()` and `multiply()` into `execute()` when all three are just functions. A possibility would be to pass those as parameters (callbacks), but it could blow up the number of parameters, and you can't typehint them as distinct types (only `callable` in PHP), so I prefer sticking to OOP with dependency injection.